# Ошибка "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" при вызове np.fromfunction

Tags: python, математика, numpy

Нужно создать вектор с помощью np.fromfunction():

```
def f(i, j):
    return np.arccos(i/(i + j + 1))
def f2(matrix, n):
    return np.min(matrix[:][n]) + np.max(matrix[n][:])

try:
    n = int(input("Введите размер квадратной матрицы: "))
    if n < 2:
        raise Exception
except:
    print("Введены неверные данные!")
    sys.exit(1)

matrix = np.fromfunction(f, (n, n))
vector_c = np.fromfunction(f2, (matrix, n))
```

При запуске программы получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой пример входных и выходных данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [np.fromfunction(function, shape, **kwargs)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) ожидает в качестве второго аргумента (`shape`) кортеж с размерностью выходной матрицы. Каждый элемент данного кортежа - целое число (число элементов по данной оси / размерности, например число строк или столбцов для 2D матрицы).

При вызове `np.fromfunction(f2, (matrix, n))` вы передаете 2D матрицу вместо целого числа и предсказуемо получаете ошибку:

> ```
> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
> ```

PS по-моему, данный вопрос является [вопросом типа "Ошибка Молотка-Микроскопа"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). Вы можете значительно улучшить ваш вопрос, прояснив изначальную проблему и приведя в вопросе пример входных и, особенно, выходных данных.